# Best way to extend Docker image to update Java and Spark

Tags: java, docker, scala, apache-spark, kubernetes-helm

I am using [bitnami/spark Helm chart](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/main/bitnami/spark) to manage a Spark cluster on Kubernetes which uses [bitnami/spark docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/spark/).

The latest version of the Helm chart uses Spark 3.3.1 with Scala 2.12.
My application jar that needs to run on the cluster requires Java 17 and Scala 2.13 ([packaged with Spark 3.3.1](https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/spark/spark-3.3.1/spark-3.3.1-bin-hadoop3-scala2.13.tgz)).

What is the best way to update the base Docker image to use Java 17 with Spark 3.3.1 with Scala 2.13?

Comment: A Helm chart can't change the code inside an image, and especially not the base image you're building from.  If you need to do major updates to an image like changing the JVM version, you'll have to recreate that image from its Dockerfile (or find a different base image or write your own Dockerfile), this isn't something that's easily changed on an already-built image.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.
This particular Helm chart provides a way to override the base image by supplying arguments (image.repository and image.tag), so I believe I can create a new image from the original base image and still use the chart without updating the chart itself.

Comment: Did you figure this out?  I was also trying to do this.

Comment: Unfortunately, I had to fork the Bitnami repo and create a custom Image.